# Create objects from different models in one handler in Piston Django

Tags: python, django, handler, django-piston

I'm using Piston to create an API for an application in Django.

I'll try to explain my doubt on an easy way.
Let's think I've got two models:

```
class Device(models.Model):
    id = models.TextField(...)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(...)
    device = models.ForeigKey(Device)
```

Now, if I receive an url like this:

```
(r'^api/(?P<person_name>\w+)/(?P<device_id>\w+)$',handler),
```

I want to add a person to the DB and, to do that, I need to add a new Device to the DB, but, since handlers in Piston are linked to a Model, how can I add a device to the DB in the same handler?

I tried something like this:

```
class PersonHandler(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods= ('PUT')
    model = Person

    def create(self, request, person_name, device_id):
        Device.objects.create(id=device_id)
        d = Device.objets.get(id=device_id)
        Person.objects.create(name=person_name,device=d)
        return rc.CREATED
```

But I guess it won't work.

How can I do what I want to do?

Comment: what is the result? How does it not work?

Comment: @oleg Haven't tried, but won't it fail because a handler it's linked to a Model, and I'm trying to create objetcs in two models?

Comment: Do not link to any model and all should work correctly